# Most optimized algorithm for incrementing squares

Tags: code-challenge

Write the "fastest" program to print an incrementing series of squares from a given input to a given input.

Example input:

```
-2
7
```

Example output:

```
4, 1, 0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49
```

When using a "cryptic" language, please post the pseudocode, in addition to your program.

The entries will be judged on the most efficient algorithm.

Comment: Oh, come on. Code challenge to write a loop or comprehend a list. Whoop dee doo!

Comment: This was the dumbest question I've ever asked.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The tag says "code-challenge", but I don't see any challenge. Just some mathematics we studied when I was about 12.

```
import java.util.*;

public class IncSquares
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int min = in.nextInt();
        int max = in.nextInt();

        int sq = min * min;
        System.out.print(sq);
        while (min < max) {
            sq += (min << 1) + 1;
            min++;
            System.out.print(", " + sq);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Technically, the fastest...the multiply will be optimized by the compiler to a single shift operation. so zero Multiplication (unlike the other answers)

Comment: Actually that's a good point - I was aiming to avoid multiplication, so I may as well be explicit about the shift.

Comment: If in doubt, the compiler probably knows best whether to represent a multiplication by 2 by a shift, a multiply or an add. The usual rule is to state your intent and let those optimize who do that for a living ;-)

Comment: @Joey, it gets complicated with Java. `javac` would emit an imul and leave it to the JIT to turn it into a shift.

Comment: Of course, that's what a JIT is for. It's still a compiler ;-)

Comment: @Peter, why don't you throw in a `sq += (min << 1) | 1`

Comment: @Peter, or maybe just calculate `k = 2*min + 1` and do a `k+=2` each time, wouldn't that be faster?

Comment: @st0le, depends how many registers there are.

Answer (score 1):

**Python**

```
print ", ".join(`x*x` for x in range(int(raw_input()), int(raw_input())+1))
```

Answer (score 1):

### C

Since my usual language interpreter has a one-second startup time already, I chose not to use it here.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int start, end, i;
    scanf("%d\n%d", &start, &end);
    for (i = start; i <= end; i++) {
        printf("%d", i*i);
        if (i != end)
            printf(", ");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Ruby

```
a,b=*$<.map(&:to_i)
p (a+1..b).reduce([a**2]){|m,x|m<<m[-1]+x+x-1;m}*?,
```

Answer (score 0):

## Jelly 12 bytes

```
+³’µ²
_N‘RÇ€
```

---

**Explanation**

```
+³’µ²
 ³’    -Decrement the first argument
+      -Sum it
   µ   -Groups the functions prior to this
    ²  -Square the result

_N‘RÇ€
_      -Subtract the two arguments
 N     -Negate the difference
  ‘    -Increment the difference
   R   -Generate Range from Difference
    Ç€ -Map range with above function
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASQA2/9qZWxsef//K8Kz4oCZwrXCsgpfTuKAmFLDh@KCrP///y0y/zc)

Comment: Jelly can do this in 2 bytes: `r²`. Now I know this isn't code golf, but I do wonder how/why your program is more efficient than that.

Answer (score -1):

```
(z + 1)^2 = z^2 + (2z + 1)
```

We already know `z^2`, and 2z is simply `z<<1`.

```
(z + 1)^2 = (z^2) + (z << 2 + 1)
```

---

Now just memorize this trick if you want to list squares in your head.

If you've got an arbitrary [two-digit] square (to do in your head), `z^2`, do this:

```
z^2 = (z-n)*(z+n) + n^2
```

Or:

```
23^2 = (23-3)*(23+3) + 3^2
23^2 = 20*26 + 9
23^2 = 520 + 9
23^2 = 529
```

Works even "faster" with larger numbers, relative to you doing `97*97` in your head. Have fun showing off.

Comment: So basically it's the same as mine but with added bugs?

Comment: @Peter Oh yes. :)

Comment: 2z != z << 2. 2z = z << 1, always.