# Calculate all the squares up to x using only addition and subtraction

Tags: code-golf, math, number

The goal is to calculate all the squares up to `x` with addition and subtraction.

Rules:

1. The code must be a function which takes the total number of squares to generate, and returns an array containing all those squares.
2. You can **not** use strings, structures, multiplication, division, or built-in functions for calculating squares.
3. You can only use arrays, integers (whole numbers), addition, subtraction. **No other operators allowed!**

This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) question, so the shortest code in bytes wins!

Comment: This is essentially [Most optimized algorithm for incrementing squares](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2469/most-optimized-algorithm-for-incrementing-squares) - or, at least, will get pretty much identical answers.

Comment: @PeterTaylor No, it's not the same, as that's for the most optimised algorithm for incrementing squares, but my question asks for only addition and subtraction.

Comment: Which is the same thing. As witness: the present answer to this question does exactly the same as the vast majority of answers to the previous question.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I might be biased, but I really don't think it's at all the same.

Comment: _This_ question may already have answers elsewhere, but that does not make the _question_ a duplicate of the other question.

Comment: @BlacklightShining and everyone who voted to reopen, please participate in [this meta thread](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1068/194).

Comment: So in ⃞⃞⃞⃞⃞⃞⃞⃞⃞x - I get 9, but how do i count ◰x?  Is that one or two?

Comment: @Charles What do you mean?

Comment: @toothbrush I calculated the squares until x...  Mostly a bad joke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes

```
+)’Ä
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/19b81HDzMMt////NzQAAA)

### How it works

```
+)’Ä - Main link. Takes x on the left
 )   - For each integer 1 ≤ i ≤ x:
+    -   Yield i+i = 2i
  ’  - Decrement each
   Ä - Calculate the cumulative sum
```

Answer (score 6):

## C, <strike>55</strike> 52 bytes

```cpp
int s(int n,int*r){for(int i=0,j=-1;n--;*r++=i+=j+=2);}
```

simply sums odd numbers

- `n`: number of squares to compute
- `r`: output array for storing the results
- `j`: takes the successive values 1, 3, 5, 7, ...
- `i`: is incremented by `j` on each iteration

### Edit

4 chars can be saved using the implicit int declaration (>C99), but this costs 1 char because `for` initializers cannot contain a declaration in >C99. Then the code becomes

```cpp
s(int n,int*r){int i=0,j=-1;for(;n--;*r++=i+=j+=2);}
```

### Usage

```cpp
void main() {
    int r[20];
    s(20, r);
    for (int i = 0; i < 20 ; ++i) printf("%d\n", r[i]);
}
```

### Output

```
1
4
9
16
25
36
49
(...)
361
400
```

Comment: that logic is Excellent! you deserve +1

Answer (score 6):

## APL - 10

```
{+\1++⍨⍳⍵}
```

Example usage:

```
{+\1++⍨⍳⍵}10
1 4 9 16 25 36 49 64 81 100
```

[ngn APL demo](http://ngn.github.io/apl/web/#code=%7B+%5C1++%u2368%u2373%u2375%7D10)

Comment: Save three bytes: [`+\1+⍳+⍳`](http://tryapl.org/?a=%u2395IO%u21900%20%u22C4%20f%u2190+%5C1+%u2373+%u2373%20%u22C4%20f%2010&run)

Answer (score 5):

#### GolfScript, 17 characters

```
{[,{.+(1$+}*]}:F;
```

Usage (see also examples [online](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=e1ssey4rKDEkK30qXX06RjsKCjEwIEYgcA%3D%3D&run=true)):

```
10 F     # => [0 1 4 9 16 25 36 49 64 81]
```

*Note:* `*` is a loop and not the multiplication operator.

Comment: OK; how does it work?

Comment: @toothbrush `,` takes the input and converts it to the array `[0 1 ... n-1]`. Then `*` injects the given code-block into the array. This block first doubles the current item (`.+`) subtracts one (`(`) and then adds the previous result `1$+` (in other words, add `2j-1` to the previous square number). `[]` encloses everything in order to return a new array.

Comment: Great! I don't know GolfScript, so I wondered how it worked.

Answer (score 5):

### Windows Batch, 115 bytes

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion&for /l %%i in (1 1 %1)do (set a=&for /l %%j in (1 1 %%i)do set /a a+=%%i
echo.!a!)
```

This should be placed in a batch file instead of being run from cmd, and it outputs the list to the console. It takes the number of squares to create from the first command-line argument. For the most part it uses `&` instead of newlines, one is still needed however and it counts as two bytes.

It needs delayed variable expansion enabled, this can be done with `cmd /v:on`. Assuming it's not, an extra `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion&` was needed at the start (without it the script is 83 bytes).

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript - 32 Characters

```
for(a=[k=i=0];i<x;)a[i]=k+=i+++i
```

Assumes a variable `x` exists and creates an array `a` of squares for values `1..x`.

## ECMAScript 6 - 27 Characters

```
b=[f=i=>b[i]=i&&i+--i+f(i)]
```

Calling `f(x)` will populate the array `b` with the squares for values `0..x`.

Comment: I have to ask... the `i+++i` at the end...?

Comment: `k+=i+++i` is the same as `k += i + (++i)` which is the same as `k+=i+i+1` followed by `i=i+1`

Comment: Oh that is genius... I've gotta implement that in my next codegolf if needed! :)

Comment: You can save one character by moving the function declaration to inside the array (e.g. `b=[f=i=>b[i]=i&&i+--i+f(i)]`).

Comment: Thanks - saved one character on the top answer too by moving things round to remove a semi-colon.

Answer (score 4):

## Haskell - 30

```
f n=scanl1(\x y->x+y+y-1)[1..n]
```

This uses the fact that `(n+1)^2=n^2+2n+1`

Answer (score 4):

### Perl, 27 bytes

```perl
sub{map{$a+=$_+$_-1}1..pop}
```

**Math:**

$$
\text{square}\left(n\right) = \begin{cases}
0                                            &  \text{for } n = 0 \\
\text{square}\left(n - 1\right) + n + n - 1  &  \text{for } n > 0
\end{cases}
$$
$$
\text{square}\left(n\right) - \text{square}\left(n - 1\right)
= n^2 - \left(n - 1\right)^2
= 2n - 1
$$

**Script for calling the function to print 10 squares:**

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
$square = sub{map{$a+=$_+$_-1}1..pop};
use Data::Dumper;
@result = &$square(10);
print Dumper \@result;
```

**Result:**

```
$VAR1 = [
          1,
          4,
          9,
          16,
          25,
          36,
          49,
          64,
          81,
          100
        ];
```

**Edits:**

- Anonymous function  (−2 bytes, thanks [skibrianski](/questions/21796/calculate-all-the-squares-up-to-x-using-only-addition-and-subtraction/22073?noredirect=1#comment51780_22073))
- `pop` instead of `shift` (−2 bytes, thanks [skibiranski](/questions/21796/calculate-all-the-squares-up-to-x-using-only-addition-and-subtraction/22073?noredirect=1#comment52152_22073))

Comment: I see no reason why you need to name your sub. IOW "sub{map{$a+=$_+$_-1}1..shift}" seems legit to me, and saves you two chars.

Comment: @skibrianski: An anonymous function is also a function. The downside is that the calling of the function is a little more cumbersome.

Comment: Right, but that's on the caller. There are entries in other languages that define anonymous subs, so I think you're safe =)

Comment: And you can save another 2 chars by using pop() instead of shift() since there's only one argument.

Comment: @skibrianski: Right, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

### Julia - 33

Any square number can be written by a summation of odd numbers:

```
julia> f(x,s=0)=[s+=i for i=1:2:(x+x-1)];f(5)
5-element Array{Int64,1}:
  1
  4
  9
 16
 25
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to CG.se! Nice, succinct answer. Never heard of Julia, but it looks intriguing.

Comment: Isn't "2x" a multiplication in Julia?  You could say x+x instead, which will cost you just one byte.

Comment: You are right (didnt notice), edited.

Comment: I'm not familiar (yet) with julia, but looked it up in the online manual at http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.2 and found "Numeric Literal Coefficients: To make common numeric formulas and expressions clearer, Julia allows variables to be immediately preceded by a numeric literal, implying multiplication."  So yeah, 2x is a multiplication.

Answer (score 2):

## C++ <strike>99</strike> <strike>81</strike> <strike>78</strike> <strike>80</strike>  78

```
int* f(int x){int a[x],i=1;a[0]=1;while(i<x)a[i++]=a[--i]+(++i)+i+1;return a;}
```

my first try in code-golf

this code is based on
a = 2 x n - 1
where **n** is term count and **a** is **n** th term in the following series
1,  3,  5,  9,  11,  13,  .....
sum of first 2 terms = 2 squared

sum of first 3 terms = 3 squared
and so on...

Comment: Well done! It's quite good.

Comment: Oops looks like I included iostream unnecessarily

Comment: more compression

Comment: I think you can remove the braces `{}` after the `for` loop, since there is only one statement. This can reduce your char count by 2

Comment: `while(i<x)` is the same size and cleaner (in my opinion) than `for(;i<x;)`.

Comment: Standard C++ doesn't support arrays of non constant size. What compiler allows this?

Comment: If you declare arrays of non-constant size in some function other than main() then it's acceptable

Comment: VS still wouldn't let me run it.

Comment: @MukulKumar Visual Studio.

Comment: I use DEV C++ 5.5.3 editor with 'MinGW GCC 4.7.2 32' compiler  [visit here to download](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Programming/Coding-languages-Compilers/DEV-C.shtml)

Comment: This code has undefined behaviour.

Comment: and returns pointer to data on stack destroyed during the return.

Comment: @V-X I know that this code is not good but dangerous but its code-golf and I programmed the code according to rules and he says to return the array so I did(consider Rule.1).

Comment: @MukulKumar I should fix my what? My answer? It doesn't use `-1` as an array index... It doesn't use `-1` at all, it subtracts 1 from `x+y+y`

Comment: @MukulKumar `addition, subtraction`, I'm only using those

Answer (score 2):

### DCPU-16 Assembly (90 bytes)

I wrote this in assembly for a fictional processor, because why not?

```
:l
ADD I,1
SET B,0
SET J,0
:m
ADD J,1
ADD B,I
IFL J,I
SET PC,m
SET PUSH,B
IFL I,X
SET PC,l
```

The number is expected to be in the X register, and other registers are expected to be 0. Results are pushed to the stack, it will break once it reaches 65535 due to the 16 bit architecture. You may want to add a `SUB PC, 1` to the end to test it.
Compiled, the program should be 20 bytes (10 words).

Answer (score 2):

### Haskell

```
f x=take x [iterate (+y) 0 !! y | y<- [0..]]
```

This basically invents multiplication, uses it own itself, and maps it over all numbers. `f 10` = `[0,1,4,9,16,25,36,49,64,81]`. Also `f 91` = `[0,1,4,9,16,25,36,49,64,81,100,121,144,169,196,225,256,289,324,361,400,441,484,529,576,625,676,729,784,841,900,961,1024,1089,1156,1225,1296,1369,1444,1521,1600,1681,1764,1849,1936,2025,2116,2209,2304,2401,2500,2601,2704,2809,2916,3025,3136,3249,3364,3481,3600,3721,3844,3969,4096,4225,4356,4489,4624,4761,4900,5041,5184,5329,5476,5625,5776,5929,6084,6241,6400,6561,6724,6889,7056,7225,7396,7569,7744,7921,8100]`.

Comment: Can you extend the demo to a little larger than 10?

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, 34 / 23

```hs
n#m=m+n:(n+2)#(m+n)
f n=take n$1#0
```

or, if imports are okay:

```hs
f n=scanl1(+)[1,3..n+n]
```

Output:

```hs
λ> f 8
[1,4,9,16,25,36,49,64]
```

Answer (score 1):

### Javascript 47

`function f(n,a){return a[n]=n?f(n-1,a)+n+n-1:0}`

`r=[];f(12,r);console.log(r)` returns :
`[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100, 121, 144]`

Comment: Great! In EcmaScript 6: `f=(n,a)=>a[n]=n?f(n-1,a)+n+n-1:0`.

Comment: I really can't wait for ECMAScript 6 to really enter mainstream use. That would be the perfect excuse to learn it.

Comment: The Arrow Function part of the ECMAScript 6 specification has been in FireFox since version 22.

Answer (score 1):

## Smalltalk, 52

```
f:=[:n||s|(s:=1)to:n collect:[:i|x:=s.s:=s+i+i+1.x]]
```

Returns a new array (i.e. does not fill or add to an existing one).

call:

f value:10

-> #(1 4 9 16 25 36 49 64 81 100)

Answer (score 1):

**Fortran II|IV|66|77, <del>134</del> <del>122</del> <del>109</del> 105**

```
  SUBROUTINES(N,M)
  INTEGERM(N)
  K=0
  DO1I=1,N
  K=K+I+I-1
1 M(I)=K
  END
```

Edit: removed inner loop and used @mniip's Haskell algorithm instead.

Edit: Verified that the subroutine and driver are valid Fortran II and IV

Driver:

```
  INTEGER M(100)
  READ(5,3)N
  IF(N)5,5,1
1 IF(N-100)2,2,5
2 CALLS(N,M)
  WRITE(6,4)(M(I),I=1,N)
3 FORMAT(I3)
4 FORMAT(10I6)
  STOP  
5 STOP1
  END
```

Result:

```
$ echo 20 | ./a.out
   1     4     9    16    25    36    49    64    81   100
 121   144   169   196   225   256   289   324   361   400
```

Answer (score 1):

## C# - 93

```
int[]s(int l){int[]w=new int[l];while(l>=0){int i=0;while(i<l){w[l-1]+=l;i++;}l--;}return w;}
```

When called from another method of the same class, will return the array - `[1,4,9,16,25,36...]`,
up to `l`th element.

Comment: did you try removing the spaces between `int[]` and `sq`? I don't know C#, but I think it should work.

Comment: No, that wont work. First int[] is the return type of method "sq". I can reduce the method name to may be just "s" :)

Comment: I mean using `int[]sq` instead of `int[] sq` and `int[]res` instead of `int[] res`. This helps you save two chars, and I didn't get any compilation errors with that. Also you should use single character identifiers for `sq` and `res` as you suggested.

Comment: seems like there's something wrong with your answer

Comment: Indent code with 4 spaces to put it in a code-block with monospace font.

Answer (score 1):

**Bash - <del>92</del> <del>85</del> <del>62</del> <del>61</del> <del>59</del> 57**

```
declare -i k=1;for((i=0;i++<$1;k+=i+i+1));do echo $k;done
```

Result:

```
$ ./squares.sh 10
1
4
9
16
25
36
49
64
81
100
```

Edit: I replaced the inner loop with the algorithm from @mniip's Haskell solution.

Answer (score 1):

## python - 39

```
a=0
for i in range(5):a+=i+i+1;print(a)
```

Replace `5` with any value. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Same method as above, in APL and J:

APL: `F←{+\1+V+V←¯1+⍳⍵}` (17 characters) works with most APL variants (try it [here](http://www.tryapl.com/))

and even less (only 14 characters) with NGN APL: `F←{+\1+V+V←⍳⍵}` (see [here](http://ngn.github.io/apl/web/index.html))

J: `f=:+/\@(>:@+:@:i.)` (18 characters)

**edit:** better solution in APL: `F←{+\¯1+V+V←⍳⍵}` (15 characters)

Answer (score 1):

## C# (82)

```
int[] s(int n){int i,p=0;var r=new int[n];while(i<n){p+=i+i+1;r[i++]=p;}return r;}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python - 51

Here I'm defining a function as requested by the rules.

Using `sum` of odd numbers:

```
f=lambda n:[sum(range(1,i+i+3,2))for i in range(n)]
```

This only uses `sum` (a builtin which performs addition) and `range` (a builtin which creates arrays using addition). If you object to `sum`, we can do this with `reduce`:

```
def g(n):v=[];reduce(lambda x,y:v.append(x) or x+y,range(1,i+i+3,2));return v
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 92 bytes

This needs to have the "short tags" option enabled, of course (to shave off 3 bytes at the start).

```
<? $x=100;$a=1;$r=0;while($r<=$x){if($r){echo"$r ";}for($i=0,$r=0;$i<$a;$i++){$r+=$a;}$a++;}
```

Output:

```
1 4 9 16 25 36 49 64 81 100
```

Answer (score 1):

### Forth - 48 bytes

```
: f 1+ 0 do i 0 i 0 do over + loop . drop loop ;
```

Usage:

```
7 f
```

Output:

```
0 1 4 9 16 25 36 49
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 9 bytes

```
ɾ(n:+‹)W¦
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%C9%BE%28n%3A%2B%E2%80%B9%29W%C2%A6&inputs=10&header=&footer=)

It could be just two bytes if everything is allowed

Answer (score 0):

### Pascal, 182 B

This is your standard [odd number theorem](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/OddNumberTheorem.html).
$$
n^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(2i - 1\right)
    = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(i + i - 1\right)
    = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(i\right) + \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(i\right) - \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(1\right)
$$

```pascal
type Z=integer;L(n:Z)=array[1..n]of Z;P=^L;function Q(n:Z)=q:P;var i:Z;begin
new(q,n);q^[1]:=1;for i:=2 to n do q^[i]:=q^[i-1]+i;for i:=1 to n do begin
n:=q^[i];q^[i]:=n+n-i end end;
```

Disgolfed:

```pascal
    type
        { This declares an Extended Pascal schema data type. }
        integerList(length: integer) = array[1‥length] of integer;
        { It is not possible to create new data types in routine signatures. }
        integerListReference = ↑integerList;
    
    { In Pascal functions cannot return variably‑sized values
      therefore a (constant‑sized) pointer is returned. }
    function squares(order: integer) = result: integerListReference;
        var
            { `For`‑loop counter variables must be _proper_ variables.
              It is not possible to re‑use `order` for that purpose. }
            i: integer;
        begin
            { Allocate memory and discriminate the schema data type.
              The value of `order` becomes the `length` of `integerList`. }
            new(result, order);
            { Dereference pointer and assign `1` to the first element. }
            result↑[1] ≔ 1;
            { In Pascal `for` loop limits are inclusive.
              `i` becomes `2`, `3`, …, `order − 2`, `order − 1`, and `order`.
              An empty range (that means 2 > order) is legal and
              just causes the `for`‑loop body to be never executed. }
            for i ≔ 2 to order do
            begin
                result↑[i] ≔ result↑[pred(i)] + i
            end;
            { In Pascal `for`‑loop limits are evaluate exactly once.
              Therefore a redefinition of `order` is harmless. }
            for i ≔ 1 to order do
            begin
                order ≔ result↑[i];
                result↑[i] ≔ order + order − i
            end
        end;
```

Note, Pascal has a built‑in square function named `sqr`.
It returns an `integer` value for an `integer` argument, a `real` value for a `real` argument, and – in case of Extended Pascal (ISO 10206) – a `complex` number in case of a `complex` argument.